# Convergence as $N \rightarrow \infty$ of weighted sample mean

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have a distribution $f$ with mean $\mu$ and finite variance. I'll sample $N$ values from this distribution $x_1, x_2, ... , x_N$. We know by law of large numbers that
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_i x_i = \mu$$

Now consider a **strictly decreasing** function $g:\mathbb R^+_0 \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$. Consider the values $y_1, y_2, ... , y_N$ where
$$y_i = g(|x_i - \mu|)$$

I'd like to know what the following converges to
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_i x_i y_i}{\sum_i y_i}$$

As it gives more weight to the numbers closer to the mean, it should converge to the $\mu$, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn’t necessarily converge to $\mu$.  You’re giving more weight to things near $\mu$, so if the distribution is skewed, you’ll give one side less weight.

One counter example is to give $X$ pdf $e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=e^{-x}$

If you want something easy to compute, the same exponential distribution for $X$ works with $g(x)$ being $1-\epsilon x$ when $x<1$ and $\epsilon/x$ otherwise. Letting $\epsilon$ tend to 0 gives a simple to compute number which I think gives a limit of $(1-1/e^{-2})/(1-1/e)=1+1/e\neq 1$

Answer (score 1):

The variables $y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_N$ are IID, since you are applying the same deterministic function to each of the IID variables $x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_N$. Similarly the variables $x_1y_1, x_2y_2, \ldots, x_Ny_N$ are IID. So writing
$$\frac{\sum x_iy_i}{\sum y_i}=\frac{\frac1N\sum x_iy_i}{\frac1N\sum y_i}
$$ you should be able to obtain an almost sure limit by invoking the law of large numbers on the numerator and denominator of the RHS.

Comment: Would it be possible that the value doesn't converge to $\mu$? Is there any other simplification I could do?