# Convergence as $N \rightarrow \infty$ of weighted sample mean for a symmetric distribution

Tags: statistics

Not sure what the protocol is there is an additional question. This is in continuation from my previous question: [Convergence as $N \rightarrow \infty$ of weighted sample mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4696724/convergence-as-n-rightarrow-infty-of-weighted-sample-mean/4696755#4696755)

From the answers, if the distribution is skewed, I'll be giving more weight on one side. So now my question is if the distribution $f$ is symmetric, does the weighted sample mean converge to the mean $\mu$? How can I show this?